# Change display output mode in system tray?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I attached my laptop to my tv, and I wanna be able to change the output from laptop display to tv or tv to laptop, with one click ( and choose their resolutions)

and I do NOT like the FN+F5 shortcut , because I have to hit it 4 different times to make it go to the mode I want.

in older versions of Ubuntu there was a system tray to change the display output with a single click, I can't find that in ubuntu, I am using 14.10, I can't find same thing here anymore.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not aware of any solution for this being part of Ubuntu, there is a thrid-party package called `disper-indicator` that you can use. While it hasn't been updated in a while, it still works fine :-)

1. Download and install this package: http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/indicators/ubuntu/pool/main/d/disper-indicator/disper-indicator_0.4.14~saucy~NoobsLab.com_all.deb (its for Ubuntu 13.10 but works in newer versions anyways)
2. Open the Dash
3. Enter `disper` and launch `Disper Indicator`
4. Checkout the new indicator (especially the `Monitor setup` submenu) that should have been added to the panel:
   [image: Disper Indicator screenshot]

To make it launch on every login:

1. Open the Dash
2. Search for and launch the `Startup Applications` preferences window
3. Click `Add` on the right-hand side of the dialog
4. Enter a name (such as `Disper Indicator`) next to `Name:`
5. Enter `disper-indicator` (make sure the casing matches!) next to `Command:`
6. Finish by clicking `Add` in the dialog
   [image: Startup Applications screenshot]

Don't forget to mark as accepted answer if this was helpful!

Comment: the tray icon wont show up for me, do I have to add it to whitelist?